# java static variables and cache

Tags: java, multithreading, static, affinity

I have two threads and they are both reading the same static variable (some big object - an array with 500_000_000 ints).

The two threads are pinned to a cpu (1 and 2) (cpu affinity) so minimize jitters.

Do you know if the two threads will slow down each other because of the static variable is read by both threads running on different cpu?

```
import net.openhft.affinity.AffinityLock;

public class BigObject {
    public final int[] array = new int[500_000_000];
    public static final  BigObject bo_static = new BigObject();

    public BigObject() {
        for( int i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
            array[i]=i;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Boolean useStatic = true;
        Integer n = 2;
        for( int i = 0; i<n; i++){
            final int k = i;    
            Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    BigObject b;
                    if( useStatic){
                        b = BigObject.bo_static;
                    }
                    else{
                        b = new BigObject();
                    }
                    try (AffinityLock al = AffinityLock.acquireLock()) {
                        while(true){
                            long nt1 = System.nanoTime();
                            double sum = 0;
                            for( int i : b.array){
                                sum+=i;
                            }
                            long nt2 = System.nanoTime();
                            double dt = (nt2-nt1)*1e-6;
                            System.out.println(k + ": sum " + sum + " " + dt);
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            new Thread(r).start();
        }
    }   
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: just added some code

Comment: Arrays are always allocated on heap - no matter, if you reference them from static or local variable. Reading the memory on one CPU shouldn't affect the performance of the other one (on typical x86 cpu)

Comment: It depends entirely on the memory architecture of your machine. If the CPUs contend for the same bus, then yes, there will be a performance hit. The only way to find out is test under conditions that approximate your intended use case. There's no general answer.

Comment: *static class members* a no proper way of inter process communication. You should better implement the *Producer/Consumer* pattern.

Answer (score 1):

In your case there won't be a slow down from doing it multi-threaded - since you're doing only reads no need to invalidate any shared state between your CPUs.

Depending on the back-ground load there could be bus limitations and stuff, but if the affinity is defined at the OS level as well - there would be more inter-CPU and inter-core communications at an easily pre-fetched manner (since you access the data sequentially) than memory-cpu communications. Back-ground load would affect the performance in single-threaded case as well - so there's no need to argue about it.

If the whole system is dedicated to your program - than you would have approximately ~20Gb/s memory bandwidth on modern CPUs which is more than enough for your data-set.